# concatenating of String seems not to work as expected

Tags: julia

I got `(".", "t1.5UTR1")` rather than `(".t1.5UTR1")` with the following code:

```
geneIDextension=splitCurrentID[2]
tmp = ".",geneIDextension  
println(tmp)
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`*`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.:*-Tuple%7BUnion%7BAbstractChar,%20AbstractString%7D,Vararg%7BUnion%7BAbstractChar,%20AbstractString%7D,N%7D%20where%20N%7D) to concatenate strings:

```
julia> "foo" * "bar"
"foobar"
```

The comma operator (`,`) does not concatenate: it creates tuples. This is why `tmp` is a tuple in your example.

Comment: I changed it to `tmp = "."*geneIDextension` and got `.", "t1.5UTR1")` rather than `".t1.5UTR1"`. What did I miss?

Comment: Your example shows `geneIDextension` is a string. If so, then `"."*geneIDextension` should work. Is `geneIDextension` not a string?